# Changing css depending on radio:checked property not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Why is this not working in safari but works in chrome and firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/1ze83qcc/

Just click on the radio buttons and if you click login it should show the div.

```css
.form-list .login-mobile{
 display:none;
}
.form-list #login-drop:checked + label + .login-mobile{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="form-list">
<li style="margin:5px 0;padding:0;">
<input id="login-drop" type="radio" name="checkout_method" selected="false">
<label for="login-drop">Login</label>
<div class="login-mobile">
    hey you
</div>
    
</li>
<li style="margin:5px 0;padding:0;">
<input id="login:register" type="radio" checked="checked" value="register" name="checkout_method" selected="false">
<label for="login:register">Register</label>
</li>
<li style="margin:5px 0;padding:0;">
<input id="login:guest" type="radio" value="guest" name="checkout_method" selected="true">
<label for="login:guest">Checkout as Guest</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: first of all, don't bother with Safari on windows as it's buggy as hell. If this problem persists on IOS as well, consider .form-list #login-drop:checked + .login-mobile for your css route (and also moving the div between the input and the label. This seems to fix the problem, but you will need to work with some positioning to get the result you want. hope this helps

Comment: @Gho yes indeed there is an issue with the css route in safari when using the `+` Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, safari seems to have a bug regarding adjacent sibling selectors: `element + element + element{}`.

So I've used the sibling combinator `~`

```
.form-list #login-drop:checked ~ .login-mobile{
    display:block;
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: There's no need for the `~ label` selector here.

Answer (score 0):

please add :nth-child(n) to label

```
.form-list #login-drop:checked + label:nth-child(n) + .login-mobile{
    display:block;
    }
```