# Radio tabs not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

The below sample works in FireFox, Chrome and even my iPhone, but not on Safari for Windows 5.1.6.  It may work on Safari for Mac, but without a Mac, it's difficult to confirm.  While having it work on Safari for Mac would suffice, I would rather find a solution that will have this render correctly on Safari for Windows.

The sample:

```css
#locations {
  width: 500px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tab-label {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 45%;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  color: gray;
  background: black;
  display: block;
}

.tab-label:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.tab-content {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}

input[type=radio],
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+.tab-label {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+.tab-label+.tab-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="locations">
  <input type="radio" id="tab-tab1" name="group" checked="checked" />
  <label for="tab-tab1" class="tab-label">TAB1</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    TAB1 Content
  </div>
  <!--TAB1-->
  <input type="radio" id="tab-tab2" name="group" />
  <label for="tab-tab2" class="tab-label">TAB2</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    TAB2 Content
  </div>
  <!--TAB2-->
</div>
<!--locations-->
```

This was somewhat based off of the following [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/vulpesigni/pen/yyZYNy/), which also seems to have 'issues' on safari.

A somewhat related question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852090/changing-css-depending-on-radiochecked-property-not-working-in-safari).

Any help?

Comment: FYI, works fine on safari 11.0.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao Thanks for that.  Upon further review, it looks like apple dropped support for Safari for Windows years ago.  So, it's not really a valid browser to test on.  If Safari 11.0 is the current Mac version, add this as an answer (perhaps with a bit more of a description) and I'll mark as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)), the last supported version of safari for windows was v5.1.7 and was discontinued on May 9, 2012. So definitely, it is a dead browser on the windows platform and developing for it with new systems in mind is a pointless endeavour. Unless your target audience requires you to support  this browser, you're better off developing without keeping that in mind.